# Path to layout xml files in magento

Tags: layout, magento-1.7

I have seen that we can place our layout xml files in

> app/design/frontend/default/default/layout

or we can place our customization inside

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

file, but I have read at [magebase](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/) and at [magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) that we can place our layout files under

> app/design/frontend/your_interface/your_theme/layout/

or

> app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/layout

So if we I have package like 'Kaushikamdotcom' in 'app/code/local', should I have to create that same package under 'app/design/frontend/' ? I tried many patterns, but nothing worked out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sorry that I have made such a blunder asking this question, but I am answering this as lots of people will be making the same mistake. **Package** means; in the admin side of magento open

> **System->Configuration->Design**

Then change the **configuration scope** to **Main website**. Then select **Package** section, uncheck the default check box and use your package name such as "Test". Then create the following folder structure.

> **app/design/frontend/Test/default/layout**

Place your layout xml files here. If you are using your own themes use that name instead of **default**.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what layout-xml file you have.

If you want to build up your theme, use the `local.xml` file in your theme dir.

If you write an extension and want to add a block to use inside this new extension, add a layout-xml file via `config.xml` and add it under `base/default/layout/yourname.xml`

When you do it this way, your theme-related changes only appear in the theme and your extension-related changes are theme-independent